# Extract text from first line of text input in AppleScript

Tags: regex, text, applescript

I have a macOS **Automator** workflow with a **Run AppleScript** action.

The action receives text (multiple lines of JavaScript code), and the first line of the text will usually be this:

`/* filename.js */`

The *filename* will always be different, but in some cases the line won't exist.

I need the AppleScript action to return whatever text is in place of *filename*.

In a case where that line does not exist (no *filename.js* could be found), it needs to return *Unknown*.

**Update**: Someone voted to close this question because it was too broad, or there were too many possible answers.

To be more specific: This is what my AppleScript looks like:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    return filename
end run
```

I the script will return a variable called "filename," but I need to know what line to put above it that extracts the filename from the first line of text.

I tried some code found in the first few results [here](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+applescript+read+lines+from+text), but I could not figure out how to do specifically what I'm trying to do.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Get the first line of text in the text input
2. Search that string with a regex to get the string between the first space and the ".js"
3. If the regex produces nothing, return Unknown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `input` is the text try this, it identifies a valid line by the javascript comment tokens `/*` `*/`

```
set firstLine to item 1 of paragraphs of input
if firstLine starts with "/*" and firstLine ends with "*/" then
    return text 4 thru -4 of firstLine
else
    return "unknown"
end if
```

Comment: This works, thank you! When I first ran it I was getting an error `Can’t get item 1 of {}.`, then I used `display alert class of input` to determine that the input text was actually type `list`. Then I used code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289223/convert-applescript-list-in-to-string) to convert the list to type `ctxt`, and then was able to use this code above to work with the text.